# Can't access old input and data is lost with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a form whose input values should be filled with the old values with `Input::old()`:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => '/directions', 'method' => 'get', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('origin', 'Origin', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ Form::text('origin', Input::get('origin'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('destination', 'Destination', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ Form::text('destination', Input::get('destination'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            {{ Form::submit('Buscar', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

In the routes I created the view like this:

```
Route::get('/directions', function() {
    $origin = Input::get('origin');
    $destination = Input::get('destination');

    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" . $origin . "&destination=" . $destination . "&sensor=false";

    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents(str_replace(" ", "%20", $url)), true);
    $result = var_export($json, true);

    return View::make('home.index')->with('directions', $result);
});
```

However, it seemed like the old input values were not passed to the view, so I changed the last line with this:

```
return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()->with('directions', $result);
```

Now `Input::old()` keeps without getting the old input values, but `Input::get()` does. Also, the variable `directions` is detected as null in the view.

What am I doing wrong? Why aren't the values passed to the views?

Comment: `Redirect()->with()` is passing variable in `Session`, not to the view. What is the problem with Input::old(), when is it not set?

Comment: when I send the form the old value is not taken in the input boxes using `Input::old()`

Comment: You mean when the form is invalid and you redirect back? Show the code where you do that

Comment: no, it is not invalid. You just send it and the same page with the form is loaded so you can make another search. I would like to keep the old values in the input after sending the form. All the logic is in the code I posted, I am not using any controller yet since I am just doing some tests.

Comment: Then you can't use `Input::old` just like that. `Redirect ... ->withInput()` sets these values in the session, while returning `View` has nothing to do with that. If you want old input then you need to put it in the session `Session::flashInput(Input::all());` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your last line is:

```
return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()->with('directions', $result);
```

then in your views you can have access to every input parameter using:

```
Input::old('parameter');
```

In order to get access to the passed `directions` you have to use `Session`:

```
{{ Session::get('directions') }}
```

If you don't like this and you want to use your very first choice:

```
return View::make('home.index')->with('directions', $result);
```

in order to have access to your inputs in your views, right before that add:

```
Input::flash(); or Input::flashOnly('origin', 'destination');
```

now in your views `Input::old('origin')` shall work as wanted.